# fetchXml: How to select accounts that *don't *have link entities of a specific type

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to select accounts that are not n:n-related to a specific entity using fetchXml. What I tried is the following:

```XML
<fetch mapping="logical" count="50" version="1.0">
    <entity name="account">
        <attribute name="name" />
        <order attribute="name" />
        <link-entity name="xy_accounthierarchynode" from="xy_accountid"
                            to="accountid" link-type="outer">
            <filter>
                <condition attribute="xy_accounthierarchynodeid"
                             operator="null" />
            </filter>
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

The expected result of this query are all acounts that don't have a related xy_accounthierarchynode. But what I receive are all accounts. The filter conditions seems to be simply ignored...

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news is this is not possible in crm 2011. You are getting all accounts because you are using an "Outer" join.

There have been a couple of creative ways of getting around this. For example to get Accounts or Contacts without Opportunities you could use the Marketing List approach described in [this](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2012/10/16/searching-for-accounts-contacts-without-opportunities/) blog post.

Good news is that CRM 2013 which will be released next month supports "Left Outer" joins which will give you the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```XML
<fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="accountid" operator="null" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="xy_accounthierarchynode" to="accountid" from="xy_accountid" link-type="outer" alias="n_0" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```